# Zip file downloaded via batch file/cmd is corrupted

Tags: batch-file, curl, cmd

`curl -o ./Makent-files.zip "https://github.com/Mapagmataas/Makent/archive/refs/heads/files.zip" --ssl-no-revoke`

downloaded zip file is corrupted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the parameter "-L" / "--location" to instruct curl to follow the location.
Example:

```
$ curl -L -o ./Makent-files.zip "https://github.com/Mapagmataas/Makent/archive/refs/heads/files.zip"

$ zipinfo Makent-files.zip 
Archive:  Makent-files.zip
Zip file size: 9948 bytes, number of entries: 2
drwx---     0.0 fat        0 bx stor 21-Dec-29 11:20 Makent-files/
-rw----     0.0 fat   105662 bx defN 21-Dec-29 11:20 Makent-files/Makent.ico
2 files, 105662 bytes uncompressed, 9626 bytes compressed:  90.9%
```

Excerpt from the curl manpage:

```
      -L, --location
              (HTTP) If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this option will make curl redo the request on the new place. If used  together  with
              -i,  --include  or -I, --head, headers from all requested pages will be shown. When authentication is used, curl only sends its credentials to the initial host. If a redirect takes curl to a different host, it will not be able to in‐
              tercept the user+password. See also --location-trusted on how to change this. You can limit the amount of redirects to follow by using the --max-redirs option.

              When curl follows a redirect and if the request is a POST, it will send the following request with a GET if the HTTP response was 301, 302, or 303. If the response code was any other 3xx code, curl will re-send the following  request
              using the same unmodified method.

              You can tell curl to not change POST requests to GET after a 30x response by using the dedicated options for that: --post301, --post302 and --post303.

              The method set with -X, --request overrides the method curl would otherwise select to use.

              Example:
               curl -L https://example.com
```

Ref: https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html

*Broader explanation to extend the comment from @SomethingDark using an example*

```
# downloading the file without following the location - we are downloading a html file
$ curl -o ./Makent-files-without-minusL.zip "https://github.com/Mapagmataas/Makent/archive/refs/heads/files.zip"  

# downloading the file with following the location - we are downloading the zip file befind the location redirect.
$ curl -L -o ./Makent-files-with-minusL.zip "https://github.com/Mapagmataas/Makent/archive/refs/heads/files.zip" 

# one file on your disk is a zip file and the other one the html file
$ file *
Makent-files-with-minusL.zip:    Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract, compression method=store
Makent-files-without-minusL.zip: HTML document, ASCII text, with no line terminators
```

Comment: I dont realy understand how, but it helped me. Thank you Benjamin!

Comment: @Mapagmataas - Github doesn't serve files directly; they're stored on a separate server and when you try to access the files you get redirected there. `curl` doesn't redirect by default, so you were initially just downloading the redirection page.